# Joint table with itself and print unique pairs

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to self-join a table and print pairs of citizens that stay at the same building

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.citizen AS, b.citizen, a.home
FROM   table_citizen a,  table_citizen b
WHERE a.home = b.home 
GROUP BY a.citizen 
ORDER BY a.citizen
```

However, that returns both

```
citizenA citizenB Hilton
citizenB citizenA Hilton
```

but I would like to keep only one pair since this is just the same result. I did something like

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  table_citizen a),  table_citizen b
```

but that does not seem to work..

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a proper join with an `ON` clause which should include the condition `a.citizen < b.citizen` so that you get each pair only once:

```
SELECT a.citizen AS citizen1, b.citizen AS citizen2, a.home
FROM table_citizen a INNER JOIN table_citizen b
ON a.home = b.home AND a.citizen < b.citizen 
ORDER BY citizen1
```

There is no need to use `GROUP BY`.
See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c9f32bd9d686bc64bb7fd393ed65ca62).

Answer (score 0):

Order the two citizen fields. Something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT min(a.citizen, b.citizen) AS citizen1,
                max(a.citizen, b.citizen) AS citizen2,
                a.home
FROM table_citizen AS a
JOIN table_citizen AS b ON a.home = b.home
ORDER BY citizen1, citizen2
```

(Note change to normal join syntax instead of your decades-obsolete pre-ANSI SQL version).